# How to delete element from jsonb nested array

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, jsonb

I have table in postgresql 13.12 with jsonb column.
Records in this column consist array of objects and looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "in": {
            "categories": [
                "648572c2-ab21-4857-bae2-ae29ef7a2024",
                "99e6d8a8-1b61-491b-98b0-ef4308c9d4f4"
            ]
        },
        "out": {
            "someOut": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "in": {
            "categories": [
                "fccba83f-519c-4623-8b0d-600ceea629a0",
                "cbab93b8-46aa-4fb6-a9fb-e465e2d21a74"
            ]
        },
        "out": {
            "someOut": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "in": {
            "categories": [
                "fccba83f-519c-4623-8b0d-600ceea629a0",
                "a7242e6f-23d4-475c-bfd5-a409ec8e769b"
            ]
        },
        "out": {
            "someOut": 0
        }
    }
]
```

I want to delete elements from "categories" array, for example I want to search if there is an uuid "fccba83f-519c-4623-8b0d-600ceea629a0" in "categories" and if it exist I want to delete it. Just the UUID, rest of array should stay as is.

I did try to search for solution, wrote some queries but eigher it's invalid or updates 0 rows.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First flatten the JSONB column then remove the array element and then rebuild the JSONB object. Use the above as a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) in an UPDATE statement.
Here is an illustration.

```sql
select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(
 'out', j -> 'out', 
 'in', jsonb_build_object(
   'categories',
   (j -> 'in' -> 'categories') - 'fccba83f-519c-4623-8b0d-600ceea629a0'
  )
))  
from jsonb_array_elements (the_jsonb_value) j;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EjoKGbGN)

Use this as a scalar subquery:

```sql
update the_table set the_jsonb_column = (
 select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(
   'out', j -> 'out', 
   'in', jsonb_build_object('categories', (j -> 'in' -> 'categories') - 'fccba83f-519c-4623-8b0d-600ceea629a0')
  ))  
 from jsonb_array_elements(the_jsonb_column) j
);
```

Unrelated but pls. note that this is neither straightforward nor efficient. Things might be so much easier, cleaner and faster with a normalized data design.